# Is there any way to use array contents in object destructuring

Tags: javascript

I have an array containing elements I want to destructure it and use them as object destructuring.

I have this code in which I am destructuring keys from req.body.

```
 const {
        city,
        companyName,
        contactName,
        contactTitle,
        country,
        email,
        fax,
        password,
        phone,
        role,
    } = req.body;
```

And I want to use an array for this all data,
eg.

```
 const temp = [
        city,
        companyName,
        contactName,
        contactTitle,
        country,
        email,
        fax,
        password,
        phone,
        role,
       ];
```

and use this array as keys in object destructuring
 According to me:

```
const { [... temp ]} = req.body;
```

I know this is wrong but is there something I can use this array and destructure that elements from req.body.

Comment: So if I understand correct, you have a list of property names in array and you want to use it in destructure like `const { [... temp ]} = req.body;`? If yes, I don't think you can. Variable names should be defined at compile time. Yes you can have dynamic assignment in object like `{ [propertyName]: value }` but for variable names, I dont think you can

Comment: You cannot create dynamic variables. You could create a partial object with only properties from the `temp` array

Answer (score 0):

As Rajesh mentioned in the comments, you can't do that.

Object deconstruction is some sugar syntax to help you write cleaner code in most of the use cases. In your case, since you want something kinda specific (re-use a list of attributes names), you could create your own function that would mimic the behavior you want :

```
function extractVars(from) {
    const myVarList = [
        'city',
        'companyName',
        'contactName',
        'contactTitle',
        'country',
        'email',
        'fax',
        'password',
        'phone',
        'role'
    ];

    const vars = {};

    for (let v of myVarList) {
        vars[v] = from[v];
    }

    return vars;
}

const vv = extractVars(req.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `req.body` is an object containing all the key/values, and you just want the values in the `temp` array, try:

```
const temp = Object.values(req.body)
```

If you also want the keys exposing as variables in the containing function's 
scope, you're best to create a temp object to store them, e.g.:

```
let tempObj = {}
Object.keys(req.body).forEach(key => { tempObj[key] = req.body[key] })
```

`tempObj` will then contain the key/values, e,g. `tempObj.city`, `tempObj.companyName`.

Hope this helps!